# JNI local references to classes

Tags: java-native-interface

When working with object references in JNI, I can use `NewLocalRef` to (as the name implies) get a new local reference to the same object.

This is useful when implementing a wrapper in C++. The copy-constructor can invoke `NewLocalRef` and both instances of the class' destructors can simply use `DeleteLocalRef` on their own local reference.

I'm also wrapping Java classes using a similar pattern, but calling `NewLocalRef` with a `jclass` seems to result in extremely strange (possibly undefined) behaviour.

Is there a way of achieving this using JNI built in functionality, or do I need to write my own reference counter?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what the purpose is. Could you illustrate with a code example where you would need to create additional _local_ references to the same object? As for class references, I think it makes more sense to only resolve them once, and cache them using a global reference.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I think you're right, global refs are the right way to do this. My use-case here is I have a C++ class for each Java type I'm using, which allows me to use RAII and "forget" about releasing resources. In the case of objects I could create new local refs but in the case of classes it looks like global refs are the way to go. Feel free to post it as an answer!